# Show/Hide html items in mvc application

Tags: model-view-controller, view, membership, roles

i am using membership provider to get roles for the user that logged in to my application.
But, i wonder how i am hiding/showing html items on the screen based on that roles?

** I am using viewModel for each of my views in the application.

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

If your app is in ASP.NET MVC, Use this:

```
          <% if(Roles.IsUserInRole("myRole")) { %>
             <!-- show my html -->
            <% } else { %>
            <!-- show something else -->
          <% } %>
```